# How can I user rails callback to limit tags before a model is saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, limit

I have set my app's show page to display a limited number of tags per post using

```
Post.tag.find(MAX_NUM)
```

I don't want to use validations, instead I want my model's `before_save` or `before_create` strip off the tags if they exceed the `MAX_NUM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do the tags get assigned in the first place? Usually there is some method such as tag_list equals. Just catch that and keep only the first five, such as:

```
def tag_list= tags
  tags = tags.split(',').map(&:strip)
  tags = tags[0..4]
  ... Save tag list ...
end
```